# Showing an image without specifying src in xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to show an image, depending on the value of the `int imgch`

This is in my onCreate:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gimage);
    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable gameImage = res.getDrawable(images[imgch]);
```

And this in my XML:

```
     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/gimage" />
```

How do I get it to show the correct image in the activity?

Comment: You could set the image using Java code - setImageResource or Drawable.

Comment: I have used Drawable right? what should I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this `ImageView#setImageDrawable`. So you should have image.setImageDrawable(gameImage)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but with java-side code

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gimage);
img.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image_name));
```

If you wanna load from an remote url you may be use this

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: But I can't give the name because it is dependent on the value of imgch. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Look bellow, I add the answer as independente answer

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Resources resources = getResources();
image.setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.myfirstimage));
```

Comment: Please elaborate **why** this answers the question by editing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array

```
int[] images;
```

on

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

add this

```
images = new int[3];
images[0] = R.drawable.first_image;
images[1] = R.drawable.second_image;
images[2] = R.drawable.third_image;
```

and then your code (where imgch is an integer)

```
...
Drawable gameImage = res.getDrawable(images[imgch]); 
...
```

Comment: this is what I already have, now what should the XML look like?

Comment: The xml is right... Do you have any error in the console log?

Comment: no but it shows nothing, the imageview takes zero spaces in the linearlayout

Comment: are you putting the content from Drawable to your image?
img.setImageDrawable(gameImage);
Also, what if you set and static size (width and height) to the image and not wrap_content?